# Identify unknown Atmel chip

Tags: hardware, embedded, pcb

wondering if folks can help identify this chip.

[image: ATMLH017]

It looks like

```
ATMLH017
2FCM  CN
©2017AB4
```

Googling all manner of permutations on these numbers has not been helpful.
The chip appears next to an ATMEGA1284P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.waveshare.net/datasheet/ATMEL_PDF/AT24C512C.PDF

```
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
  A   T   M   L   H   Y   W   W
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
  2   F   C   M               @
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
  ATMEL LOT NUMBER
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
  |
PIN 1 INDICATOR (DOT)
LINE 1: ATML=ATMEL H=MATERIAL SET/GRADE YWW=DATE CODE
LINE 2: 2FC=AT24C512C, M=1.7 to 3.6V, @=COUNTRY OF ASSEMBLY
LINE 3: ATMEL LOT NUMBER
```